# darknet: ./src/image.c:41: get_pixel: Assertion `x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c' failed

Tags: darknet

I trained yolov4-tiny on a custom dataset using google colab, got the best weights, and used them to make predictions on my images. If there is an object in the image, the predictions are correct and I could see them when I used the flag `-ext_output`.

However, the predictions.jpg file doesn't contain the predicted bounding box and I get the error

> darknet: ./src/image.c:41: get_pixel: Assertion 'x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c' failed.

as shown in the picture.

[image: Here is a snapshot from my google colab notebook]

I think the problem is with the image.c file but I have no clue on why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /src/image.c in 41 line
and

Do `//assert 'x < m ~~~~~~~~`

Comment processing and it's done